# numpy power applied to float matrix returns zero

Tags: python, numpy

I will be brief. I have the following first few elements of the matrix `x`

`0 1.6e-9 4.12e-8 1.93e-8`

when I go and do

```
x2 = x**2
```

or

```
x2 = np.power(x,2)
```

it returns the following:

```
0 2.402575684e-18 0 3.714390431e-16
```

Notice the zero in the second position.

Anybody got any idea why that can be?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Running it on my computer i get [0.00000e+00 2.56000e-18 1.69744e-15 3.72490e-16]